# How can i set cookies in java HTTP client?

Tags: java, cookies, httpclient

```
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", getSessionId());

//cookie.setDomain("your domain");
cookie.setPath("/");

cookieStore.addCookie(cookie); 
httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore); 
response2 = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

i am not able to compile them.. What should i import to get methods getSessionId() and setCookieStore() ?

Comment: You definitely don't import methods. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: The server assigns the session, not the client...

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(postData); 
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", getSessionId());

//cookie.setDomain("your domain");
cookie.setPath("/");

cookieStore.addCookie(cookie); 
client.setCookieStore(cookieStore); 
response = client.execute(httppost);
```